# What is the recommended path to put your seed data files to be used in seeds.rb file in a Rails 5 project?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, seed

I have some static records with which I want to initially populate a table in my database.

Either I can write create statements for those records in seeds.rb file or I can make them to be read through a file (txt or csv) in the seeds.rb file. The second way is more manageable as to alter the seed records I would not need to change the code in `seeds.rb` file.

What is the recommended place to place that data file in a rails 5 project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put them alongside `seeds.rb`

```
config
|--db
   |--seeds.rb
   |--data
      |--file1.csv
      |--file2.txt
```

Comment: Is there actually any recommended path for such data files or is it completely up to the developer?

Comment: @Farooq: I don't know about any "official" position on this, but I imagine they'd agree with this one. If you plan to use the fixtures from seeds.rb, it makes sense to keep them close together.